# Comparing and object with others in a list

Tags: java, list, compare

I got this strange problem. I am working with different objects that belong to different classes. What I am trying to do is to see if a object is equal or not to another one that is  possibly inside another object using a recursive algorithm:

```
private static void foundObject(EObject obj, EObject set) {

        if(EcoreUtil.equals(obj, set)){
                System.out.println("The objects are the same: \n\t"+obj+"\n\t"+set);
                return;
        } else {
                System.out.println("The objects are not the same: \n\t"+obj+"\n\t"+set+" "+set.eContents());        
                if(set.eContents().size()>0){
                    for(EObject child: set.eContents()){
                        foundObject(obj, child);
                     }
                 }
        }           
}
```

And I want to see if a Object of the Assignment class is inside or not the group:

- Assignment
- Group **[Assignment, Keyword]**

As you can see, inside the Group object there is a list with the object that I want to find. In this case I am having the next output:

```
> The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    Group [Assignment, Keyword]
The objects are the same: 
    Assignment
    Assignment
The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    Keyword
```

Which is right. The problem is, when the initial group gets another Assignment element

> Group [**Assignment**, Keyword, **Assignment**]

the algorithm does not see the corresponding match and provides an output like this:

```
The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    Group [Assignment, Keyword, Assignment]
The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    Assignment
The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    RuleCall
The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    Keyword
The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    Assignment
The objects are not the same: 
    Assignment
    RuleCall
```

But in my case the second pair of elements are the same (that is why I am using ECoreUtil.equals). 
Any idea about why this could be happening?.

Comment: bad format. No one is going to read your code. At least if you don't bring it to some readable format

Comment: If all your debugging is external to the code you've posted people will have no idea what's happening.